# (iphone) how to animate several images with speed variations between images?

Tags: iphone, animation, performance

this must have been asked and answered but couldn't find an answer.

What I'd like to do is basically animating images like

image1 0.1sec
image2 0.3sec
image3 0.2sec
image4 0.5sec

I have looked at CAKeyFrameAnimation but can't be sure if that's what I needed.
(have almost none image/animation programming background)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CAKeyFrameAnimation is for one object to animate differently in different phases of one animation. For example, your object first moves to a point, then continues the same animation to another point, then one another.

You can use CABasicAnimation with different duration values for each image you want to animate.

```
CABasicAnimation *anim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position.x"];
anim.delegate = self;
anim.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
anim.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:50.0];

anim.duration = 0.1;
[image1 addAnimation:anim forKey:@"position.x"];
anim.duration = 0.3;
[image2 addAnimation:anim forKey:@"position.x"];
anim.duration = 0.2;
[image3 addAnimation:anim forKey:@"position.x"];
anim.duration = 0.5;
[image4 addAnimation:anim forKey:@"position.x"];
```

Comment: Thanks what does timingFunction do? when there's individual duration for each image. and what is "forKey" and "toValue"?

Comment: ah, one more thing, if i want to animate two set in one screen at the same time, I need CAAnimationGroup? and CAAnimationGroup supports above functionality as well?

Comment: timingFunction is for defining the timing of the animation. For example, kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut starts with slow speed. Gets faster to a point. And at the end of the animation slows back to the speed of 0 when the animation is ended. Or you may use kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear for constant speed.

Comment: forKey is for naming the animation for future access. You may name it anything you want. toValue is the destination of the animation. In this example, all images will move to the point (50.0, <their y position>)

Comment: CAAnimationGroup is for joining two animations. For example, an object can move on the x axis and zoom at the same time.